# incremental slide in class:middle: stuff move around

Tags: xaringan, remarkjs

Text is moving when the list got larger because it wants to be in the middle, any way to change that behaviour while keeping the elements in the middle (as in the last or first version of the slide)

```
---
title: "SFB1315 Result Gallery"
subtitle: "what is the point?"
author: " "
institute: ""
date: "2019-10-24 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["default" ]
    chakra: libs/remark-latest.min.js
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: true

---
class: middle

# Objectives:

- bullet 1

--

- bullet 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
---
title: "SFB1315 Result Gallery"
subtitle: "what is the point?"
author: " "
institute: ""
date: "2019-10-24 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: true
---

<style>
.middle-freeze{
padding-top: 12em;
}
</style>


---
class: middle-freeze

# Objectives:

- bullet 1

--

- bullet 2
```

Explanation: I added 12em padding to the top of the main content, so it doesn't get pushed up when the height is changed.